# Get the data with a between condition

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have query

```
select * from TABLE_NAME 
where date 
between to_date('26/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') 
and     to_date('26/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi');
```

> 01/26/2016 11:59:32 PM

above one is the date which need to fetch when running the query

But when i running the same query it was not able to filter. Don't know why?

I don't know where i am doing wrong.

Comment: What does "not able to filter" mean?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  Your `to_date` functions appear to have a format mask that doesn't match the strings that you're using.  Not sure if that is your problem or a bug preparing the question.

Comment: like from this query i am not getting any data but actually it has a data which i mentioned above.. NO i am not getting any error.. I simply want to take whole day when i insert same date in between clause.

Answer (score 1):

> between to_date('26/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') and to_date('26/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')

You do not have any **time portion** in `to_date('26/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')` at all. You only have **date portion**, so the filter will ignore the time portion and return all the rows for that date. The time portion in your query is:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT to_date('26/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') FROM dual;

TO_DATE('26/01/2016
-------------------
26/01/2016 00:00:00
```

To filter the rows with `01/26/2016 11:59:32 PM` you need:

```
TO_DATE('01/26/2016 11:59:32 PM' ,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')
```

Comment: hey i only entering the date not the time how can i format my query so that it will take the whole day

Comment: Then provide the create and insert statements. And show your desired output.